# Flutter Future.delayed on endless loop

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I'm running this code

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((value) => {opened = false,setState(() {}), value = "null"});
```

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getStorage();
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500))
        .then((value) => {opened = false, setState(() {}), value = "null"});
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
            height: opened ? 0 : 300,
            width: opened ? 0 : 300,
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Lottie.asset('assets/101349-swing.json'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and it returns

```
I/flutter (22251): false
```

continually and I want to avoid because I think it is inefficient.

Comment: Can you include full widget?

Comment: class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
getStorage();
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((value) => {opened = false,setState(() {}), value = "null"});
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
home: Scaffold(
body: Container(
color: Colors.green,
alignment: Alignment.center,
child: AnimatedContainer(
duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
height: opened ? 0 : 300,
width: opened ? 0 : 300,
curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
alignment: Alignment.center,
child: Lottie.asset('assets/101349-swing.json'),),),),);}}

Comment: opened is defined in another file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding `Future.delay` inside the `build` method and this is a StatefullWidget, build method can calls multitple time, like whenever you call `setState()` build method will trigger and recall the `Future.delay` which provide infinite loop in your case.

To call single time, override `initState`, you can do something like this,

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initFuture();
  }

  _initFuture() async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500))
        .then((value) => {opened = false, setState(() {}), value = "null"});
  }
```